# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ClientCacheService {
    private _cacheMode: CacheMode;
    private _cacheMode: CacheMode;
    constructor(cache?: CacheMode) {
        if(!cache)
            this._cacheMode = CacheMode.SessionStorage;
        else
            this._cacheMode = cache;
    }

    setToCache(key :string, prefix:string, definition: any) {
        if(this._cacheMode === CacheMode.SessionStorage)
            window.sessionStorage.setItem(`${prefix}_${key}`, JSON.stringify(definition));
        else if(CacheMode.Memory)
            window["`${prefix}_${key}`"] = JSON.stringify(definition);
    }

    getFromCache(key :string, prefix:string) {
        let res = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`${prefix}_${key}`);
        if (res) return JSON.parse(res);

        return undefined;
    }
}
export enum CacheMode{
    Memory,
    LocalStorage,
    SessionStorage
}
```

When the constructor of the class `ClientCacheService` is called, it is shown the following message:

> ```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ClientCacheService -> Number]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ClientCacheService -> Number]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for Number!
> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ClientCacheService -> Number]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ClientCacheService -> Number]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for Number!
> ```

I have put a `breakpoint` on the line `this._cacheMode = cacheMode;` and the debugger launches the error before reach this `breakpoint`.

I'm not understanding why this errors is been shown. Any one have any idea what this means and how to solve it?

Comment: What value should be passed as `cache`?

Comment: @abetteroliver an enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to Inject enum that is not injectable, you should implement an abstract class with a single interface for Memory, LocalStorage and SessionStorage, Lets call it StorageService for example, next you should consume it in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(storageService: StorageService) {}
```

finally the providers array

```
providers: [
    { provide: StorageService, useClass: Memory} // or LocalStorage or SessionStorage
]
```